# Vertically aligned content

Tags: html, css

My link wraps to the second line when it's to long to fit. The problem is that it's not vertically aligned with the first word. How can I do that?

```css
color: #353748;  
font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 400;
line-height: 20px;
padding: 10px;
text-indent: 10px;
text-decoration: none;
```

[How it looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKIB9.png)

Comment: Post the relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

It may be fault of the indentation and you may be able to fix it by getting rid of `text-indent` and putting some horizontal margin if the text is too wide.

Comment: putting some horizontal margin if the text is too wide how do I do that. Thanks

Comment: Something like 
margin: 0 10px;

Which adds no vertical margin, but 10px of horizontal margin